# how to create a callback on model.get in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following (**edited to show `currencyId`**):

```
var currencyId  = $(".listSelected").attr("rel"); // 110
var currencies = new Currencies();
currencies.fetch({
    success:function () {
        var currency = currencies.get(currencyId);
        user.symbol = currency.get("symbol");
        user.country = currency.get("country");
    }
});
```

Occasionally I get the following exception.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined on
currency.get("symbol");
```

My guess is that I need to wrap the `get` statement inside a callback. How would I do this?

Comment: where is `currencyId` defined? If it is `undefined`, `currency` will be `undefined` too, so it won't have any `get` method

Comment: If currency is not defined, then no currency in your currencies collection is being found with the id 'currencyId'.

Comment: Are you certain that you have a `.listSelected` element? And that it has the `rel` attribute that you're expecting? And that your currency collection is supposed to have that currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currency = currencies.get(currencyId);
```

would not work as the variable currencyId is not defined.

If you need to access an attribute of a model, the **attribute** would have to be **wrapped inside a string** when calling [get](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get).

```
var currency = currencies.get("currencyId");
```

Comment: apologies. I left out the currencyId definition.